# How to add back icon image in app bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter i need to add back icon image in app bar in flutter. I m new to flutter learning & developing any help would be appreciated.

I need to customise the back button image in app bar

Please let me know How to add back icon image in app bar in flutter?

Comment: what do you mean by "Back Icon Image" ? You want a button that redirect you to the previous screen of your app ?

Answer (score 1):

Back **IconButton** is automatically enabled when you Navigate from another screen.

By using this code

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
```

If you already Navigated from another screen  and are still not showing then slightly change the AppBar field

```
AppBar(
automaticallyImplyLeading:true,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget call : BackButtonIcon()

```
AppBar(
   leading: IconButton(
   onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
   },
   icon: const BackButtonIcon(),
                          ),)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use an `AppBar` widget in your Scaffold, the back arrow icon will be displayed automatically when you push a new page with the `Navigator`.

If you want to add manually the icon, you can add it in the `leading` property inside the AppBar:

```dart
AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(
    icon: const BackButtonIcon(),
    onPressed: () { },
  )
);
```